# Sent BTC to Jaxx Wallet Never Received

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, qrcode

A friend suggested I use Jaxx Wallet so I downloaded the software and sent my BTC using their QR Code from Coinbase. Looking back, I should've left it where it was!

It never arrived. I also sent LTC using the same QR Code method. That has arrived and is in my Jaxx Wallet now.

I see my transaction completed and verified on the blockchain. How do I locate where it is?

How can I trace that this transaction was actually sent (and maybe received) by Jaxx although it doesn't show in my wallet?

Comment: This is really a service question for either Jaxx or Coinbase, or both.

Answer (score 1):

try resetting the cache on jaxx and let it re-sync, the coins should show up